# findstr - syntax for comma-delimited list of directories

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to locate all SQL scripts that contain the word "sysobjects" in 3 folders: Tables, Views, Sprocs.  The /s (searches subdirectories) is not suitable because within the 3 folders listed above are folders for Obsolete and Backup scripts and those are to be ignored.  The /d: looks like it might do the job to restrict the search to the 3 folders -
*/d: dirlist   : Searches a comma-delimited list of directories.*
However, I have not hit on the correct syntax for creating the comma-delimited list to feed into /d:.  Here is an example of what's been tried:
`findstr /i /m /c:"sysobjects" /d:"Tables, Views, Sprocs" *.sql > results_sysobjects.txt`
This results in an error: **FINDSTR: Cannot open Tables, Views, Sprocs**.  What is the correct syntax for the comma-delimited list for the /d: parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searches the specified list of directories. Each directory must be separated with a semicolon (;), for example dir1;dir2;dir3.

Found on
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc732459(v=ws.10).aspx

I have never used this, but it could help you